# index of summation in cplex

Tags: optimization, indexing, cplex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wp6V.jpg)
Hi,
In my cplex code, I have to consider an index summation which is a parameters like what I showed in the picture. Can you help me how I can code it in cplex?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum:

```
range T0=5..6;

int v[i in 1..10]=i;

int su=sum(i in T0) i;

assert su==11;

execute
{
  writeln(su);
}
```

which gives

```
11
```